# Unity 'Transform does not contain a definition for Position'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform

Unity gives an error, here is the code I used:

```
void MoveCharacter()
{
    myRigidBody.MovePosition(
        transform.Position + change * speed * Time.deltatime
    );
}
```

}

Comment: It is [`transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) .. lower case `p` .. voting to close this as typo-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is a case sensitive programming language.
You wrote transform.Position instead of transform.position.

You also tried to make operations on transform.position which is invalid.
If you want to make an operation on the position then you must declare x or y.
So, transform.position.x + 5 is valid However, transform.position + 5 is invalid.